# Unwanted whitespace in Erb view

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

Here's my sinatra code:

```
get '/' do
    foo = 'not bar'
    erb :index
end
```

My layout.erb

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

My index.erb

```
<div class="container">
</div>
```

now the problem is 
[image: screen shot of problem]

The extra text (hilighted with yellow) disturbs my design
Any idea why this is happening?
this dosn't happen if I dont use layout and use only index.erb with all html code

[Edit:]
Use of <%= yield -%> throws error (unexpected tUMINUS, expecting kEND ; @_out_buf.concat " "; - yield -; @_out_buf.concat "\n" ) in .... layout.rb

Comment: forgot to mention Use of <%= yield -%> throws error (unexpected tUMINUS, expecting kEND ; @_out_buf.concat " "; - yield -; @_out_buf.concat "\n" ) in .... layout.rb

Comment: <div class="container"> is in index.erb. .. thats the only content

Comment: You are getting an output `"     
     "`? (quotes containing a newline)?

Comment: @zabba yes its a new line char in quotes

Comment: For sinatra add, `set :erb, :trim => '-'` to use -%> rails has this automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

my best guess is the 4 spaces come from the soft tabs in your layout.erb

```
<body>
____<%= yield %>
</body>
```

try `<body><%= yield%></body>`?

I've been using Slim a long while
and

```
body
= yield
```

never fails me whitespace

hate ERB

Comment: +1 Erb is not just for HTML, and does not attempt to do anything 'smart' with whitespace removal. Your layout told it _"Create a body tag, then a newline, then some spaces, and then put another string in there."_ So that's what it did. If you don't want the whitespace, the easiest way to remove it is to not include it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set this up with *trim_mode* parameter for ERB

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html#method-c-new :

If trim_mode is passed a String containing one or more of the following modifiers, ERB will adjust its code generation as listed:

```
%  enables Ruby code processing for lines beginning with %
<> omit newline for lines starting with <% and ending in %>
>  omit newline for lines ending in %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think it is not possible to remove other white spaces with those options, only a single newline.